# ngClick does not fire inside label tag

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to fire a click event to toggle show password. That's my code:

HTML

```
<div class="show-password" ng-click="toggleShowPassword();">
    <i class="ion-ios-eye-outline" ng-show="!showPassword"></i>
    <i class="ion-ios-eye" ng-show="showPassword"></i>
</div>

<label>
    <input type="password" ng-model="myPassword" ng-show="!showPassword">
    <input type="text" ng-model="myPassword" ng-show="showPassword">
</label>
```

JS

```
$scope.showPassword = false;
$scope.toggleShowPassword = function() {
    $scope.showPassword = !$scope.showPassword;
}
```

[image]
[image]

The problem is: Outside of `<label>`, the funcition works fine (above). But if I place the `<div class="show-password">` inside of `<label>`, the function `toggleShowPassword()` just won't work.

Should I really place the `div` insde of `label` ou just leave it this way? (It's working anyway, but it does not feel right).

Is there another way to achieve this function?

Comment: HTML does not allow to contain a `div` into a `label` try to change the `div` with a `span`

Comment: Instead of creating two `input` elements, I would create a single one, and change only it's `type`.

Comment: `<input type="{{inputType}}" ng-model="myPassword" ng-show="!showPassword">` and in the toggle function change `$scope.inputType`.

Comment: @Michelem I changed from `div` to `span` and the function still does not firing.

Comment: @neptune The thing isn't really the input, but the icon click that will fire the function. When I place it inside of `label` it does not work.